# Nav bar disappears at 769px width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, nav

I am using the Bootstrap `navbar-fixed-top` method to create a floating nav bar.

I have a few issues I cannot figure out:

- Why are my logo and my social icons disappearing when I reduce screen-width to 769px?
- Why is my logo and social icons right at the top of the page?
- My social icons are too small and bunched up next to each other. How do I change this?

http://codepen.io/dhruvghulati/pen/qrdNBm

What should I do to have a persistent nav bar which is more standard?

Comment: Please, take some time to [read the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). Everything in `collapse` will collapse < 768px. Also, clarify the question to one issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.collapse class looks like this:

```
.collapse {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And there is:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block!important;
    height: auto!important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible!important;
    visibility: visible!important;
}
```

Which means .collapse will be not displayed until screen is 768px width.

Also there is (used for logo):

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-left {
    float: left!important;
}
```

That makes logo float left since screen is 768px width, there is similar class for `.navbar-right` which is used for social icons container.

Comment: Understood, this makes total sense! What would you suggest in this case? And also what about the icons being bunched to top and together?

Comment: By default, bootstrap displays button for menu when screen is less than 768px, but you seem to removed that functionality, If you want to display your navbar same for even that small screen, then remove that .collapse class, so it wont be hidden by default, and bring those .navbar-left .navbar-ritht classes out of @media min-width condition. It will still need some touches after all but they should be visible, and logo will be on left, icons will be on right.

Comment: I want the whole thing to stay fixed as I move down the page so it is always visible. I used what @H. Allen said below. How do i do this?

Comment: See bootstrap's documentation http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Answer (score 1):

You should probably visit the official [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/) to get more information on navbars. I would use this as the template for your navbar and go from there:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Essentially, Bootstrap replaces your nav link with a hamburger button at that screen size. Also, you should give the logo the proper classes (from the code above) to make sure it's always visible. To make the navbar stick to the top of the page, simply add the `navbar-fixed-top` class to the nav tag. the opening tag should now look like this: `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">`.

Comment: What is specifically causing the 3 issue cited? I don't need a lot of the functinality e.g. toggles in what you have given in your answer.

Comment: I addressed two of your issues at the bottom of my answer. Also, I understand that you don't need everything in the code, but this is the template given in the official Bootstrap docs. You need to use the navbar properly in order to make it do what you want.

Comment: You are right, I tried this and it does the job to an extent. I want the whole thing to stay fixed as I move down the page so it is always visible. How do i do this?

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll add that to my answer. But, all you need to do is add the `navbar-fixed-top` class to your nav.

Answer (score -1):

I think its because you are using `position:absolute;` try using `position: relative;` instead

Comment: I'm sorry can you be more specific? Where am I using `position:absolute`? It isn't in my codepen CSS.

Comment: He needs a static navbar this is why its absolute.